# c# list compare

Tags: c#, list, compare

Hi I need to find a way to compare many (c#) List objects to output what numbers occur in each one.

E.g.

```
List1{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
List2{1, 3, 6, 8}
List3{1, 2, 3}
```

this would return {1, 3}

Comment: What have you tried to solve this problem?  What methods on the List class do you know that may help solve this?  This looks like a homework problem where I'd want to see what have you done to solve this before giving hints or an answer as I don't want to do your work for you here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the Linq extension method [Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx).

> var result =
>   List1.Intersect(List2).Intersect(List3);

Answer (score 1):

LINQ intersect is built for that.