# Compare two List<> on C#

Tags: c#, object, arraylist, .net-2.0

My question is like this one: 
[c# list compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106788/c-sharp-list-compare)

but the only thing to note is this:

I'm using .NET Framework 2.0

So how can I compare two lists on C# framework 2 and return a boolean value if the items are different?

```
instance == anotherone fails
instance.Equals(anotherone) fails.
```

***Edit:***

**They are both List**

***Edit 2***

I'm trying to compare if the list values are exactly. I can sort them, np for that. The problem is if the count or the values of the items changes. For example:

```
List1->Item1 = "A"
List1->Item2 = "B"

List2->Item1 = "B"
List2->Item2 = "A"

//must return true


List1->Item1 = "A"
List1->Item2 = "B"

List2->Item1 = "B"
List2->Item2 = "C"

//must return false

List1->Item1 = "A"
List1->Item2 = "B"

List2->Item1 = "B"
List2->Item2 = "A"
List2->Item3 = "A"

//must return false, etc.
```

Thanks and kind regards.

Comment: what are the types? Your defined class instances? information is not enough, write more details please

Comment: Do you care about the order of the items in the list, or are two lists equal if they contain the same items, regardless of order?

Comment: I don't care the order because I can sort them before if is needed for comparison. I'm looking for if any was added and/or deleted and/or updated to another value.

Comment: @Leandro: No, don't sort before hand. You turn the problem from one of `O(n)` complexity to one of `O(n log n)` complexity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the question that you link to on computing the intersection, you would need to implement your own version of `Intersect`. This should get you started:

```
List<T> Intersect<T>(List<T> first, List<T> second) {
    Dictionary<T, T> potential = new Dictionary<T, T>();
    foreach (var item in first) {
        potential.Add(item, item);
    }
    List<T> intersection = new List<T>();
    foreach (var item in second) {
        if (potential.Remove(item)) {
            intersection.Add(item);
        }
    }
    return intersection;
}
```

To handle if they have the same items with the same frequency:

```
bool AreSameAsMultiSets(List<T> first, List<T> second) {
    Dictionary<T, int> counts = new Dictionary<T, int>();     
    foreach (var item in first) {
        if (!counts.ContainsKey(item)) {
            counts.Add(item, 0);
        }
        counts[item] = counts[item] + 1;
    }
    foreach (var item in second) {
        if (!counts.ContainsKey(item)) {
            return false;
        }
        counts[item] = counts[item] - 1;
    }
    foreach (var entry in counts) {
        if (entry.Value != 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

You should probably add some error-handling to the above (first is not null, second is not null). Note that you can't use `HashSet<T>` since you're in .NET 2.0.

Comment: I'm not sure `Intersect` is what he wants here.

Comment: @Rawling: The question that he links to asks how to compute the intersection. Note that my second method `AreSameAsMultiSets` addresses his question about seeing if they have the same items.

Comment: @Leandro if this answers your question you should click the check-mark below the vote arrows to "[mark as accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)"

Answer (score 4):

If you want to check if the lists contain identical items (i.e. the same items in the same order):

```
public static bool ListsEqual<T>(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
  if (list1.Count != list2.Count) return false;
  for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++) {
    if (list1[i] != list2[i]) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: OP specifies (not sure if it was added after your answer or not) that two lists are equal if they have the same items that are NOT in the same order.  For the record, I didn't downvote.

Comment: Sorry, I specified the "order detail" after the answer. I vote it up, is useful to me.

Comment: this answer can be solved with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390900/cant-operator-be-applied-to-generic-types-in-c

It's not generic but I used it, it's wonderful. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Leandro,

You could also use my open source Compare .NET Objects Library.  You would set the Config.IgnoreCollectionOrder to true.

https://comparenetobjects.codeplex.com/

```
[Test]
public void ComparerIgnoreOrderSimpleArraysTest()
{
    var a = new String[] { "A", "E", "F" };
    var b = new String[] { "A", "c", "d", "F" };

    var comparer = new CompareLogic();
    comparer.Config.IgnoreCollectionOrder = true;
    comparer.Config.MaxDifferences = int.MaxValue;

    ComparisonResult result = comparer.Compare(a, b);
    Console.WriteLine(result.DifferencesString);
    Assert.IsTrue(result.Differences.Where(d => d.Object1Value == "E").Count() == 1);
    Assert.IsTrue(result.Differences.Where(d => d.Object2Value == "c").Count() == 1);
    Assert.IsTrue(result.Differences.Where(d => d.Object2Value == "d").Count() == 1);

}
```